# when enabling errors to bigquery I do not receive the bad record number

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using [bigquery command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) to upload these records:

```
{name: "a"}
{name1: "b"}
{name: "c"}
```

.

```
➜ ~ bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON  my_dataset.my_table ./names.json
```

this is the result I get:

```
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r7fc5650eb01d5fd4_000001560878b74e_1 ... (2s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my_dataset:bqjob...4e_1': JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. 
Rows: 2; errors: 1.
Failure details:
- JSON parsing error in row starting at position 5819 at file:
file-00000000. No such field: name1.
```

when I use `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobId>` I get:

```
 {
  "status": {
    "errorResult": {
      "location": "file-00000000", 
      "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 1.", 
      "reason": "invalid"
    }, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "location": "file-00000000", 
        "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 1.", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }, 
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 5819 at file:
        file-00000000. No such field: name1.", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  }
}
```

As you can see I receive an error which tells me in what line I had an error. : **Rows: 2; errors: 1**

Now I'm trying to enable errors by using [max_bad_errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.maxBadRecords)

```
 ➜  ~ bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --max_bad_records=3 my_dataset.my_table ./names.json
```

here is what I receive:

```
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_...ce1_1 ... (4s) Current status: DONE   
Warning encountered during job execution:

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 5819 at file: file-00000000. No such field: name1.
```

when I use `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobId>` I get:

```
{
  .
  .
  .
  "status": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 5819 at file: file-00000000. No such field: name1.", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  },
}
```

when I check - it actually uploads the good records to the table and ignores the bad record,

but  now I do not know in what record the error was.

Is this a big query bug?
can it be fixed so I receive record number also when enabling bad records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is what max_bad_records does. If the number of errors is below max_bad_records the load will succeed. The error message tells you the start position of the failed line, 5819, and the file name, file-00000000. The file name is changed since you're doing an upload and load.

The previous "Rows: 2; errors: 1" means 2 rows are parsed and there is 1 error. It's not always the 2nd row in the file. A big file can be processed by many workers in parallel. Worker n starts processing at position xxxx, parsed two rows, and found an error. It'll also report the same error message and apparently 2 doesn't mean the 2nd row in the file. And it doesn't make sense for worker n to scan the file from beginning to find out which line it starts with. Instead, it'll just report the start position of the line.

Comment: what does the position tell me?
how can I calculate the record number using the position?
I'm trying to know which records weren't uploaded to bigquery

Comment: please see this question - it explains the extended issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581844/bigquery-bug-do-not-receive-all-bad-records-when-uploading-data

Comment: "The previous "Rows: 2; errors: 1" means 2 rows are parsed and there is 1 error"   - this isn't true, I did different tests  and Rows always gave me the row number - and not the number of rows parsed!!

Comment: The position is the start offset of the record in the file. In text files this basically tells you that the record starts at the nth char in the file.

Did you test with a file big enough that will be split and parsed by several workers? For small files only one worker is used and sure the rows it parsed will be equal to the row number.