# bigquery bug: do not receive all bad records when uploading data

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload data to bigquery table

here's the table schema:

```
[{
    "name": "temp",
    "type": "STRING"
  }]
```

here is my file I'm uploading:

```
{"temp" : "0"}
{"temp1" : "1"}
{"temp2" : "2"}
{"temp3" : "3"}
{"temp4" : "4"}
{"temp5" : "5"}
{"temp6" : "6"}
{"temp7" : "7"}
{"temp" : "8"}
{"temp" : "9"}
```

here is the bq command for uploading enabling errors:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --max_bad_records=100 mydataset.mytable ./tmp.json
```

I receive:

```
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_123.._1 ... (2s) Current status: DONE   
Warnings encountered during job execution:

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 15 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp1.

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 31 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp2.

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 47 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp3.

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 63 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp4.

JSON parsing error in row starting at position 79 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp5.
```

now I'm using:

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobId>
```

and this is what I get (I copied here only relevant fields):

```
{
  "configuration": {
    ...
      "maxBadRecords": 100

    }
  ,
  "statistics": {
    "load": {
      "inputFileBytes": "157",
      "inputFiles": "1",
      "outputBytes": "9",
      "outputRows": "3"
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 15 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp1.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      },
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 31 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp2.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      },
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 47 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp3.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      },
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 63 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp4.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      },
      {
        "message": "JSON parsing error in row starting at position 79 at file: file-00000000. No such field: temp5.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "state": "DONE"
  }
}
```

now when I go to my table I actually have 3 new records (which actually matches the `outputRows : 3` field) :

```
{"temp" : "0"}
{"temp" : "8"}
{"temp" : "9"}
```

**now these are my qustions:**

1. as you see I had 6 bad records I receive only 5 of them. - didn't receive temp6. Now I tried uploading files with more bad records and always receive only 5. Is this a bigquery bug?
2. assuming my records are larger and I upload many records enabling errors, after uploading how can I know which records were the bad ones? - I need to know which records weren't loaded to bigquery.
   all I get is `JSON parsing error in row starting at position 15 at file..` Position does't tell me much. Why can't I receive the number of the record? Or is there a way to calculate the record number by the position?

Comment: Copy and paste in into the Notepad ++ and click Ctrl+g and set of option is Offset that would help you find the exact line number where you facing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We only return the first 5 errors, as we don't want to make the reply too big.
2. As I explained in another thread, BigQuery is designed to process large files fast by processing them in parallel. If the file is 1GB, we might create hundreds of workers and each worker processes a chunk of the file. If a worker is processing the last 10MB of the file and found a bad record, to know the number of this record it needs to read all the previous 990MB. Thus every worker just report the start position of the bad record. Some editors support seeking to a offset in a file. In vim, 1000go will move to position 1000. In less, it's 1000P.

Comment: So if I had more then 5 errors - how can I know which records weren't loaded to bigquery?

Comment: Good question, and unfortunately the current answer is this is not supported. I agree that 5 is a bit small, but we need a boundary so the reply doesn't get too big.

Comment: If I would receive an array containing only the positions (and not the whole  error descriptions) it would solve this issue, without making the reply to big.

Comment: How about adding to "status" a field  "badRecordsPosition":[15,31,47,63,70, .. ,.. ,..]

Comment: Returning only the positions will help, but we would still need a limit anyway. If we have 1M positions, which is really not big for BigQuery, that will easily make the reply 8M bytes. Please file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/.